# How to query ndb for all properties and include keyproperty values?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb

Started this week using Google App Engine with Python Endpoints.
The goal is to query a entity and include all keyproperty values.
The models:

```
class Person(EndpointsModel):
  _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'surname', 'lastname', 'created')
  surname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
  lastname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class Magazine(EndpointsModel):
  _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'name')
  name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class Subscription(EndpointsModel):
  _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'publication', 'person', 'amount')
  magazine = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Magazine)
  person = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Person)
  amount = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

These models are queried by the following to retrieve all items:

```
@endpoints.api(name='subscription', version='v1', description='REST API for Subscriptions')
 class SubscriptionV1(remote.Service):
   @Subscription.query_method(path='subscriptions', name='subscriptions.list')
   def SubscriptionList(self, query):
     return query
```

The result is:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "created": "2015-02-13T09:40:22.514000",
   "id": "6225984592281600",
   "modified": "2015-02-13T09:40:22.514000",
   "magazine": "ahNkZXZ-YXZpYW4tc2xpY2UtODUwchgLEgtQdWJsaWNhdGlvbhiAgICAgND7CQw",
   "synced": false
  }
 ]
}
```

While I want it to be:

```
"magazine": {"id": 123456789123456789,
"name": "Tech magazine"}
```

Looked everywhere, but couldn't find a good query.
How should the query be to get this result?

Comment: Can you confirm your query is intended to return all `Subscription` entities?  Have you tried using the `response_fields` and `collection_fields` decorator parameters, like [this example](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/custom_api_response_messages.html)?  I'd be interested to know the outcome (I find Cloud Endpoints not as well documented in Python compared to Java).

Comment: Yes, the entention is to return all `Subscription` entities. No, not tried yet. I wouldn't know a way to make the query so it retrieves the `magazine` belonging to the key. In SQL I would use an inner join, but don't know in NoSQL

Comment: I haven't explored Cloud Endpoints much in Python, but I think you might need to look at using the underlying [ProtoRPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) API to create your own custom messages.  That said, bear in mind if you do a separate Datastore `get` operation on each of your `Subscription`'s `magazine` keys, it won't be very efficient.  Sure, `ndb` will cache entities, but cache misses will be costly.  [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace) will show you the RPCs behind your `subscriptions.list` API.

Comment: There is no way the query itself can get the magazine entity referred to by the KeyProperty of a Subscription entity.  You need to dereference this your self, . One possible strategy would be a computed property to store the name of the magazine in the Subscription property. In addition you will need to structure your result set yourself to meet your requirements. (Maybe the computed property could do that for you)

Answer (score 1):

If i read your code right you use endpoints proto datastore which offers `EndpointsAliasProperty`. In your example you could use it to get the correct subscription:
rename magazine to magazine_key and define a `EndpointsAliasProperty` in your model:

```
@EndpointsAliasProperty(property_type=Subscription.ProtoModel())
def magazine(self):
    if self.magazine_key != None:
        magazine = self.magazine_key.get()
        return magazine
```